# rmarkdown section numbering depth for html documents

Tags: html, format, r-markdown

I am numbering sections and specifying table of contents depth using the following in the `yaml` header:

```
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
    code_folding: hide
    theme: cerulean
```

For sections that are automatically numbered, I'm getting depth 4 sections (`#### ....`) numbered.  How can I specify the depth limit for section numbering?  I know how to suppress numbering using `#### .... {-}` but would enjoy having something more automatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of any other built in solution. And I think that the effort needed to add `{-}` is not that high.

Anyways, you could add this chunk at the beginning of your document:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo = F}
toc_depth <- rmarkdown::metadata$output$html_document$toc_depth
sel <- paste0("h",(toc_depth+1):10, collapse = " > span, ")
cat(paste0("<style>",
           sel, 
           " > .header-section-number { display: none; } </style>"))
```
````

It reads out the `toc_depth` YAML option and then prints some lines of CSS to simply hide all elements of class `.header-section-number` that belong to a heading greater than `toc_depth`.